# Laravel – передача значения во вложенную функцию

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу вывести в цикле изображения, привязанные к конкретному значению id из базы данных.
Как мне передать в функцию значение id?

```
// Controller

public function index() {
    $news = DB::table('news')
                    ->where('posted', '=', 'true')
                    ->simplePaginate(10);
    $photo = $this->photo($news->id); // ошибка здесь
    return View::make('index')
                    ->with('news', $news)
                    ->with('photo', $photo);
}

public function photo($id) {
   if(file_exists($id.'.jpg')) {
       return $id;
   } else {
       return 'default';
   }
}


// View

@foreach ($news as $news_item)
   {{ $news_item->id }}
   <img src='{{ $photo }}.jpg'>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно у вас ошибка вы пытаетесь взять id у объекта Paginator

1) Я бы советовал воспользоваться моделью и создать модель Article (и указать таблицу news)

2) Перенести логику обработки фото или получения пути в модель, например getPhotoPatch(), где вы уже сможете взять $this->id

тогда ваш контроллер будет выглядеть так:

```
public function index()
{
  $articles = Article::where('posted', '=', 'true')->paginate(10);
  return view('name')->with(compact('articles'))
}

@foreach($articles as $article)
  <img src="{{$article->getPhotoPatch()}}">
@endforeach
```